# Pixel Size field in gdalinfo command meaning

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, pixel, gdalinfo

What is the meaning of the Pixel Size field in the `gdalinfo` output on a TIFF image?

I have 2 images, one is a PAN image (size 400MB) while one is a DEM (size 25MB). Both are in TIFF format. When I run the `gdalinfo` command on these 2, I get the following:

**For the PAN image:**

Pixel Size = (0.600000023841858,-0.600000023841858)

**For the DEM:**

Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)

I also get the same values (with one extra value) when I run another command, `exiftool`, on these 2 images:

**For the PAN image:**

Pixel Scale                     : 0.600000023841858 0.600000023841858 0

**For the DEM:**

Pixel Scale                     : 0.000277777777778 0.000277777777778 0

I can see that the output is same, except that `gdalinfo` puts a `minus` sign before second value, and `exiftool` gives 3 values where the 3rd value is `0`.

What should I infer from these values? Which image has a better spatial resolution? I know its the PAN image that has a better resolution, but how do I understand that from these values?

I say this because since 0.00027 < 0.6, so one might think that the DEM has a better resolution. Just like when we say that an image has a spatial resolution of 0.25 meter while other has 0.3 meter resolution, it means the 0.25 meter one (the lower one) has better resolution. Or maybe I am understanding it wrong if I'm looking at the value of the number in this case.

Whats the unit of these numbers? Is it meters? If not, then what? Which `gdalinfo` field could tell me the unit? Right now I get this metadata field in `gdalinfo` which has the word 'unit' in it:

TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)

How to I explain someone that in this context, bigger number means better resolution, not the other way?

Some additional info that I feel might be helpful:

The metadata field AREA_OR_POINT is as follows:

**For the PAN:** - POINT

**For the DEM:** - AREA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixel size is (as it sounds) the size of a pixel in the **units of the raster's projection**. So there is nothing you can infer from just the number, 0.00027 < 0.6 might mean that the first raster is higher resolution or it may mean one is measured in feet and the other in metres (or degrees or furlongs).

Here is the `gdalinfo` output for a raster I have:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /data/os-data/rasters/ras250_gb/data/NC.tif
Size is 4000, 4000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["OSGB 1936 / British National Grid",
    GEOGCS["OSGB 1936",
        DATUM["OSGB_1936",
            SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249612664951,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7001"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6277"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4277"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","27700"]]
Origin = (200000.000000000000000,1000000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (25.000000000000000,-25.000000000000000)
```

In this case my Pixel Size is 25 metres, compared to this one:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /data/natural_earth/HYP_HR_SR_OB_DR/HYP_HR_SR_OB_DR.tif
Size is 21600, 10800
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000014)
Pixel Size = (0.016666666666670,-0.016666666666670)
```

Where the pixels are 0.016 of a degree in size but are much lower resolution.

Comment: I didn't notice the `UNIT` field in the `Coordinate System` section. I have the same 2 cases - the 0.6 value is in meters while the 0.00027 value is in degrees. Now I understand it.